# Jquery - Find value in a dynamically created div when another button is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<div id="list1">info needed for jquery script</div>
<tr>
<td><button class="button green">Click Me</button></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<div id="list2">info needed for jquery script</div>
<tr>
<td><button class="button green">Click Me</button></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

If someone clicked the click me button, how can I get the div before the tr based on the button they clicked? So if they clicked the first click me it gets the value of list1, if they click the second Click Me button it gets the content in the div called list2. The id for the div is dynamically created so it could be list25 or list100. But it will always start with the word list followed by a numeric value.

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid (not even after you put it inside a `<table>`) so the browser will rearrange it to make it valid. But, you don't know what the browser will do to your HTML to fix it so there is no portable answer. Fix your HTML and try again.

Comment: I agree with *mu is too short* because your HTML is not standard.Can you modify your HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the invalid divs inside the table;

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).parents("tr").prev("div").text();
});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `previous()` method.

Comment: Sorry, it was off the top of my head. Updated.

Comment: You can't ignore the invalid HTML, try this in a WebKit browser or Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7yX2Z/

Comment: @mu is too short it worked for me, divs are hidden. Anyway I fixed the invalid html and got it to work. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @John: Try this in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, or Opera and note where the divs are: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7yX2Z/

Comment: @muistooshort I posted the answer before answers specifically about the invalid HTML... My comment was not to say that he shouldn't deal with the html (quite the opposite; I was actually pointing it out) but I skipping over it for the sake of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think you should embed both your  tag and your button in another div, just like

```
    <div id='parent_node'>
     <div id="list2">info needed for jquery script</div>
     <tr>
     <td><button class="button green">Click Me</button></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     </tr>
    </div>
```

When 'click' event is fired, 'this' variable will become the object that fired the event, so you can use this.parent() or this.siblings() to traverse inside the parent node to find any value that you want, like :

```
   $(".button_green").click(function(){
    alert($(this).siblings()[0].innerHTML);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
$("button.button.green").click(
    function (event) {
        var button = $(this);

        console.log(button.prev("div").text());
    });
```

It might not work exactly that way for you because your HTML wasn't properly formed (you had table elements with no table). However, as you can see from this jsFiddle, it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnMunsch/VX3DR/

Once you've got your HTML finalized you'll want to tweak the traversing functions you call to get to the element you're interested in. Above I used .prev() but jQuery has many such functions, see here for the available choices:

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

They allow you to go from an element you have, to traverse the DOM and find another element.